# MySQL Query - MAX() not working on the columns

Tags: mysql, sql

MAX() doesn't seem to be working.

```
SELECT 
    PType,
    MAX(...) AS Profit
FROM
    :::
GROUP BY PType
```

I tried putting MAX() around the second attribute. I even tried wrapping a new SELECT statement around the above query to find the MAX() but it is not working. It is outputting all the rows no matter what.

Comment: you are misunderstanding what max does; it returns the maximum value of its expression argument for all rows in a group; you are grouping by prodType so your max will get the maximum value for your subquery for the prodType of each result row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ORDER BY profit` and `LIMIT` to get the wanted result

```
SELECT 
     PType,
    MAX(...) AS Profit
FROM
    :::
GROUP BY PType
order BY Profit DESC
LIMIT 1
```